# delete cipher suites with openssl ciphers command w/o re-compilation?

Tags: openssl

Is it possible to delete cipher suites with openssl ciphers command without recompiling openssl?

I ran the following command:

```
# openssl ciphers ! DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
```

but when I listed with openssl ciphers again, the cipher is still there.

Any comments are welcome

Comment: Delete from what? `openssl ciphers` just lists ciphers. It doesn't change the configuration of software that's using OpenSSL.

Comment: I would like to delete the cipher suite from the system so that it's not used by any applications.